# Return value of a row when cell value is less than a give number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two rows in my excel sheet

Row 1: Dates listed from Today through June

Row 2: Numbers below each date

```
3/24 3/25 3/26 3/27 3/28.........6/1 6/2 6/3
70   85   100.  50.  49.......... 45 30   1
```

Now I have another number, lets say 25. I want to write a formula that searches the numbers in row 2 and returns the date when the value in row 2 is less than or equal to 25.

I am trying to use the lookup formula but that's for a specific match. i am trying to write a formula that's looking to see If the value is less than 25, then return the date

Comment: It would be appreciated if your question had a mock example that could easily be transferred over to excel.

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are not the same thing. They are owned by different companies, and they are not entirely compatible. If your question is about Excel, then the Google Sheets tags are not appropriate. Tag spamming is a very good way to quickly get your post downvoted and closed. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should be used **only** when they actually apply to your post.

Answer (score 1):

### Match If Less Than Or Equal

- I am using the old `MATCH` on purpose since I have encountered huge lags when using `XMATCH` (or `XLOOKUP`) for a **not exact match**. AFAIK, it's not been fixed yet.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:I2,B3,-1)),C1:I1,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula

```
=MAP(A3:G3,A2:G2,LAMBDA(xx,zz,(XLOOKUP(51,xx,zz,,-1))))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]